# How to bind multiple authentications to single user object with warden_omniauth

Tags: omniauth, padrino, warden

I'm trying to introduce social login with warden_omniauth into my project that is based on Padrino.

I want to enable multiple authentications for one user, just like [RailsCasts #236](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2).

But I found that warden will simply skip the authentication process if there is an authenticated user object in the session.
For example, if I have logged in with Twitter, I can not link my Facebook credentials to that user object.

I dag deeper, and found that in [lib/warden/proxy.rb](https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/proxy.rb), the method `_perform_authentication` bypass the further invocation of the auth strategies if the user object exists.

Is there any best practice to deal with such kind of problem?